# Expose TFS to the internet

Tags: routes, router, wan, dmz

I have had TFS installed on a home server for a long time now and I love it. Now I need to expose it over the internet because me and a few others need to work on a programming project.

I have a DLink router "DIR-825", and have done a lot of research and I am a bit stumped as to why I can not get it to work. I have tried doing port forwarding and even DMZ (with computer fire wall disabled) with my home servers IP address which is 192.168.1.08 and even in DMZ it does not work. My routers WAN address matches what Google says my IP address is.

When I place my computer outside the router everything is fine, it is only once it is in the router, that nothing can connect to it when using the WAN address.

When I use this website: http://canyouseeme.org/

It says the ports 80, 8080 and 8081 are all open on my WAN ip address.

The only thing I can think of is the router is routing my WAN ip to the wrong computer. If you guys think this is it, how would I fix that?

If this is not the case, what should I try to get this to work?

I am not expert in networking, so any advice is needed.

Thank You

Comment: If you put netmon on your TFS server, do you see packets coming in for it when a client tries to reach it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After fiddling with my router it turns out there is a section called "virtual servers". You can tell the computer to route the WAN IP with a specific port to a specific LAN IP Address.

Once this was done it started working great and everyone can connect to me.